# Operator with sigma matrices corresponding to two different spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

How can we expand the operator
$$O_{12} = \frac{1}{r^3}[({\bf \sigma_{1}\cdot{\bf r}})({\bf \sigma_{2}\cdot{\bf r}}) - r^2{\bf \sigma_{1}}\cdot {\bf \sigma_{2}}]$$ where ${\bf \sigma} = (\sigma_{x}, \sigma_{y}, \sigma_{z})$ and ${\bf r}$ is an ordinary 3-vector. Subscript 1, 2 refers to the first and second spin.

I have tried using the relation $(\sigma . {\bf a})(\sigma . {\bf b})$ but that only involves one of the spins.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The things in the square brackets are dimensionally inconsistent and will not have a physical interpretation. You might want to fix that typo.

Comment: I fixed that, but you may be missing a factor of 3 someplace?

Comment: ... if this were to be a part of a magnetic dipole-dipole interaction...

Answer (score 2):

Without context, it's hard to see what you are up to, but here is a standard identity you should be able to derive/confirm,
$$
(({\bf \sigma_{1} +  \sigma_{2})\cdot{\bf r}})^2 =  ({\bf \sigma_{1}\cdot{\bf r}})^2+({\bf \sigma_{2}\cdot{\bf r}})^2 +2({\bf \sigma_{1}\cdot{\bf r}})({\bf \sigma_{2}\cdot{\bf r}}) \leadsto \\
({\bf \sigma_{1}\cdot{\bf r}})({\bf \sigma_{2}\cdot{\bf r}})=\tfrac {1}{2}   ( ({\bf \sigma_{1} +  \sigma_{2})\cdot{\bf r}}   )^2- 2r^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The sigma matrices are the generators of the SU(2) Lie group. There is a general relationships for such generators given by the structure constants. If my memory does not fail me, it reads
$$ [\tau^a,\tau^b]= if^{abc}\tau^c . $$
In the case of the SU(2) group the structure constant is just the totally antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon^{abc}$.